# QGIS Python Standalone Script using qgis.rastercalculator

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator

I have been attempting to use the raster calculator algorithm in a standalone python script and have been trouble getting it to work. My issue is with the expression.

```
    precip = QgsRasterLayer(
    "./Rasters/Georef_Precip.tif", "Georef_Precip"
    )

    reclass_tmp = QgsRasterLayer(
    "./Rasters/Reclass_Temp.tif", "Reclass_Temp"
    )

    georef_rain = processing.run(
    "qgis:rastercalculator",
    {
        'EXPRESSION':f'{reclass_tmp}@1 * {precip}@1',
        'LAYERS':[precip],
        'CELLSIZE':0,
        'EXTENT':'-15052048.99614927,-12097374.584049538,5572589.970826002,7733078.012284913 [EPSG:3857]',
        'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857'),
        'OUTPUT':'./Rasters/New_precip.tif'
    }
    )
```

Using the above expression gives an error of "raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm."

```
    test = "./Rasters/Reclass_Temp.tif"
    precip_test = "./Rasters/Georef_Precip.tif"

    georef_rain = processing.run(
    "qgis:rastercalculator",
    {
        'EXPRESSION':f'{test}@1 * {precip_test}@1',
        'LAYERS':[precip],
        'CELLSIZE':0,
        'EXTENT':'-15052048.99614927,-12097374.584049538,5572589.970826002,7733078.012284913 [EPSG:3857]',
        'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857'),
        'OUTPUT':'./Rasters/New_precip.tif'
    }
    )
```

And, if I use this second expression it runs successfully but the outputted raster is empty.

Can you help fix my error?

Comment: Did you try 'EXPRESSION':"test@1 * precip_test@1" ?, I mean, why did you use the {} brackets?